# Using thread causes "python.exe has stopped working"

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, web-scraping, thread-safety

Recently I tried to add thread to my scraper so that it can have higher efficiency while scraping.

But somehow it randomly causes the python.exe to "has stopped working" with no further information given hence I have no idea how to debug it.

Here is some relevant code:

1. Where the threads are initiated:

   ```
   def run(self):
   """
   create the threads and run the scraper
   :return:
   """
   self.__load_resource()
   self.__prepare_threads_args() # each thread is allocated a different set of links to scrape from, these should be no collision.
   for item in self.threads_args:
       try:
           t = threading.Thread(target=self.urllib_method, args=(item,))
           # use the following expression to use the selenium scraper
           # t = threading.Thread(target=self.__scrape_site, args=(item,))

           self.threads.append(t)
           t.start()
       except Exception as ex:
           print ex
   ```
2. What the Scraper is like:

   ```
   def urllib_method(self, thread_args):

   """
   :param thread_args:  arguments containing the  files to scrape and the proxy to use
   :return:
   """

   site_scraper = SiteScraper()
   for file in thread_args["files"]:
           current_folder_path = self.__prepare_output_folder(file["name"])

           articles_without_comments_file = os.path.join(current_folder_path, "articles_without_comments")
           articles_without_comments_links = get_links_from_file(articles_without_comments_file) if isfile(articles_without_comments_file) else []

           articles_scraped_file = os.path.join(current_folder_path, "articles_scraped")
           articles_scraped_links = get_links_from_file(articles_without_comments_file) if isfile(articles_without_comments_file) else []

           links = get_links_from_file(file["path"])
           for link in links:
               article_id = extract_article_id(link)

               if isfile(join(current_folder_path, article_id)):
                   print "skip: ", link
                   if link not in articles_scraped_links:
                       append_text_to_file(articles_scraped_file, link)
                   continue
               if link in articles_without_comments_links:
                   continue

               comments = site_scraper.call_comments_endpoint(article_id, thread_args["proxy"])

               if comments != "Pro article" and comments != "Crash" and comments != "No Comments" and comments is not None:
                   print article_id, comments[0:14]
                   write_text_to_file(os.path.join(current_folder_path, article_id), comments)
                   sleep(1)
                   append_text_to_file(articles_scraped_file, link)
               elif comments == "No Comments":
                   print "article without comments: ",  article_id
                   if link not in articles_without_comments_links:
                       append_text_to_file(articles_without_comments_file, link)
                   sleep(1)
   ```

I have tried to run the script on both Windows 10 and 8.1, the issue exists on both of them.

Also, the more data it scraped, the more frequent it happens. And the more threads used, the more frequent it happens.

Comment: Are you using python 2.7 (or any pre 3.2 python)? I'll bet my tail that this is the Global Interpreter Lock screwing you over. Using threads in python pre 3.2 is not safe, period. If you want to know why, check out David Beazley's talk about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Obt-vMVdM8s

Comment: @melwil I am using python 2.7.10 :(.   Do you happen to know any method to dodge GIL fail?

Comment: Try to just not use threads, if you still run into this issue, then that might not be your problem.

Comment: @melwil I wonder besides using thread, if there is any other method that can increase the speed by several times as multithread?

Comment: Due to the way python 2.7 handles threads, you will never be able to run more than 1 at a time anyway. I realise it might help you because you want to contact several sites simultaneously. I guess you could just try to juggle a couple of sockets manually to emulate threading?

Comment: @melwil I am watching the video and kind of understanding the situation now,  maybe the simplest way is to run several copies at once and let the system handle the thread.  will this actually work (I have a 4 cores and 8 threads cpu )?

Comment: You should look into multiprocessing: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html Can't believe I didn't think of this at once, he even mentions this in the video :-)

Answer (score 0):

Threads in Python pre 3.2 are very unsafe to use, due to the diabolical Global Interpreter Lock.

The preferred way to utilize multiple cores and processes in python is via the multiprocessing package.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Hi, I am trying with the Process now but only one can be initiated.  The Error message for other processes are "Can't pickle "_subsequence_handle" object ....."

Comment: You might want to start testing multiprocessing with a smaller program to get a feel for how it works, then expand gradually. That way you will easily see what causes the problem. I'm not familiar with the exact object you gave.

Comment: After hours of debugging and etc., I found that the thing that caused most of the trouble is Windows. 

Thread method will work nicely under linux environment.
Also, in Linux process will avoid the "Pickle" method which is used mostly in windows to serialize instances.

formatting my drivers for ubuntu :(.

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't think that to be a problem to be honest. The API should be the same regardless of OS..